# Can checkout and track git branch, but cannot pull

Tags: git, merge, branch, source-control, pull

So we have a branch in our git repo called `creative_market`. I run the command `git checkout --track origin/creative_market` which works fine. All of the changes that should be on the `creative_market` branch are present. However, if I run `git pull` I get this error:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'creative_market'
>   from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

In addition, if I do `git pull origin creative_market` I get:

> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref creative_market
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Running a `git branch -a` clearly shows:

> remotes/origin/creative_market

And my `.git/config` file shows:

```
[branch "creative_market"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/creative_market
```

Which lines up with everything else in my `.git/config` file.

I am stumped here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message you're getting can indicate that the `creative_market` branch no longer exists in the remote repository. Could this be the case?

You can fix it with the following commands:

```
git checkout --track origin/creative_market
git push origin creative_market
```

Another, slightly longer, way to prove what's happening is to do the following:

First, make a backup ref with the command `git branch creative_market2 origin/creative_market`. Then, run `git fetch -p` to prune remote-tracking branches that no longer exist on the remote. If the branch was indeed deleted from the remote, you'll see something like the following:

```
[my-repository]$ git fetch -p
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/creative_market
```

To re-create the branch on the remote repository, simply push your local ref to it:

```
git push --set-upstream origin creative_market2:creative_market
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I believe you are right that the branch didn't exist anymore, so I fixed it by doing `git checkout --track origin/creative_market` and then pushing it via `git push origin creative_market` which seems to have fixed everything. I'm guessing your solution will work as well, so I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeLentini That's a much quicker fix, I added it into my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prune the local remote copy of the branch

```
git fetch -p
```

Remote the upstream of the local branch

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```